# FormValidation - dynamic condition

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, dynamic

I have a form where some of the conditions (max value) is variable depending on what the selected item in the select input. The validation script does not change its parameters with the change in value of variable max. 
Is it possible to change them with the change of values select input?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  maxg = 0;
  maxng = 0;
  $('#select_input').on('change', function(event, params) {
    SprawdzGodziny();
  });

  function SprawdzGodziny(idz) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "### HIDE_URL ###";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(response) {
      var arr = JSON.parse(response);
      maxg = arr[0].godziny;
      maxng = arr[0].nadgodziny;
    }
  }
  $('#defaultForm')
    .bootstrapValidator({
      framework: 'bootstrap',
      excluded: ':disabled',
      fields: {
        godziny: {
          validators: {
            between: {
              min: 0,
              max: maxg,
              message: 'Wartość musi być większa od 0 i mniejsza od ' + maxg
            }
          }
        },
        nadgodziny: {
          validators: {
            between: {
              min: 0,
              max: maxng,
              message: 'Wartość musi być większa od 0 i mniejsza od ' + maxng
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
});
```